# Building a half tree in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to build the following half-tree form

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
....
N xxxxx
```

but I cannot get to the "*" in the middle. Instead I have the gaps generated by the second loop.

The code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main(){ 
    int N;
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter the number: "); 
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for (i=1;i<=N;i++){
        printf("x"); 
        for(j=1; j<=(N-i); j++){ 
        printf(" "); 
        }
        printf("x");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Could you please advise how am I going to populate the *s?

Thank you in advance.

**edit** based on the comments

If I change the `printf(" ");` with `printf("x");` I get an inverted half tree, like the one below for N=6

```
xxxxxx
xxxxx
xxxx
xxx
xx
x
```

Comment: You mean the `printf(" ");` ? Why not just change that to `printf("x");` ?

Comment: Why do you print spaces at all? There are no spaces required for your pattern. Also you print at least 2*`'x'` per row. One before and one after the inner loop. That will not work for the first line.

Comment: *but I cannot get to the "*" in the middle. Instead I have the gaps generated by the second loop.* That's because the second loop prints spaces (gaps). If you don't print gaps, you won't get gaps. :)

Comment: Is `printf("x")` really supposed to be `printf('*')`?

Comment: Hey, I've made several tests and had a mistake as you mentioned regarding "*" and "x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition in your second `for` loop from `j<=(N-i)` to `j < i`.  See below.

**halfTree.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int N;
    int i, j;

    N = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("*");

        for(j=0; j < i; j++)
            printf("*");

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run the above using the commands below

```
gcc halfTree.c -o halfTree
./halfTree 4
```